# detecting change in a text input box using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

in html and javascript, I can use keyup, focus, blur to detect most of the content changes in a text input, however if the user do a copy and paste into the text input, how do I capture this change?  The issue here is that the input is already in focus when user paste into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture the paste event (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html)

```
$("#myinput").bind("paste",function(){
    //code here
})
```

Comment: That's nice! unfortunately paste is not supported in all browsers esp. FF3

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#myinput").change(function(){
    // whatever you need to be done on change of the input field
});

// Trigger change if the user type or paste the text in the field
$("#myinput").keyup(function(){
    $(this).change();
});

// if you're using a virtual keyboard, you can do :
$(".key").live('click',function(){
    $("#myinput").val($("#myinput").val()+$(this).val());
    $("#myinput").change(); // Trigger change when the value changes
});
```

Comment: change event only triggers when you leave that input field, not on every single keypress. keyup is a mess since if you're pressing tab key - it'll trigger event on the next element, the one you'll tab into (at least in firefox 5.0)! Also - you're saying that keyup event will be triggered on paste?  - that's only correct if you''ll paste via keyboard and not from browser context menu.

Answer (score 3):

the textbox has an OnChange event that fires when a) the text box loses focus AND the value within the text box has changed.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work for paste, because the focus is not lost when user pastes something into the text box

Comment: you're not catching the PASTE, you're catching the fact that the value has been modified when the user leaves the textbox.