# Sum of table's column input

Tags: javascript

I've a table as given below:

```
       <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table class="productList" width="600">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="9" align="left"> Select your product list</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="head">
        <td width="25" align="right"></td>
        <td width="270" align="center">Product Name</td>
        <td width="80" align="center">Quantity</td>
        <td width="80" align="center">Unit Price</td>
        <td width="80" align="center">Line Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><label class="arow" data-icon="&#x45;"></label></td>
        <td><select name="productname" class="datagridInput" disabled required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="datagridInput" ></td>
        <td><input name="purchase_price"type="text" class="datagridInput"></td>
        <td><input name="linetotal"  type="text" class="datagridInput" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><label class="arow" data-icon="&#x45;"></label></td>
        <td><select name="productname" class="datagridInput" disabled required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="datagridInput" ></td>
        <td><input name="purchase_price"type="text" class="datagridInput"></td>
        <td><input name="linetotal"  type="text" class="datagridInput" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><label class="arow" data-icon="&#x45;"></label></td>
        <td><select name="productname" class="datagridInput" disabled required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="datagridInput" ></td>
        <td><input name="purchase_price"type="text" class="datagridInput"></td>
        <td><input name="linetotal"  type="text" class="datagridInput" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><label class="arow" data-icon="&#x45;"></label></td>
        <td><select name="productname" class="datagridInput" disabled required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="datagridInput" ></td>
        <td><input name="purchase_price"type="text" class="datagridInput"></td>
        <td><input name="linetotal"  type="text" class="datagridInput" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><label class="arow" data-icon="&#x45;"></label></td>
        <td><select name="productname" class="datagridInput" disabled required>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" class="datagridInput" ></td>
        <td><input name="purchase_price"type="text" class="datagridInput"></td>
        <td><input name="linetotal"  type="text" class="datagridInput" readonly></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<label for="net_ammount">Net Ammount:</label>
<input type="text" name="net_ammount" class="summary" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to find sum of  each "Line Total" column input value and show in "Net Amount" input element. every input has same id actually I found them with it's row and column index value..........

data are coming from the server. when user change the product code all field get enable and when user select product total line value showing in "Total Line" column. Please check at http://www.lpgbookkeeping.in/

username: blueflame2014
password: Blueflame@2014

I want when user select product code in datagrid . Sum of all  "Line Total" show in Net Amount.

Please somebody help me........

Here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/engineersatendra/WW4M7/1/embedded/result/) of my table

Comment: what u tried so far.. ?

Comment: ID can never be same ,Id is unique,classes can be same (multiple) in HTML

Comment: @Neha actually i want to sum of "Line Total"  column value in Net Ammount Input element.

Comment: @PratikJoshi thanks for telling me my mistake. I'had coded the input values ​​by their row index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you donot have any content on linetotal input so this may give NAN, but this method u have to write and call it on button click or any other event where u wana update the textbox.

```
function getTotal() {
  var linetotal =0;    
  var line = document.forms[0].elements["linetotal"];

  for (var i = 0, len = line.length; i < len; i++) {  
       linetotal = linetotal  + parseInt(line[i].value) ;
  }
 document.getElementById("summary").value  = linetotal;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question and put the some more information about my question. Please read and visit my website to know my problem

Comment: @SatendraMishra After login where i should go to see your jsfiddle page?

Comment: No not jsfiddle page, you should go to www.lpgbookkeeping.in after login go to new purchase order entry sub menu under the supplier menu

Comment: @SatendraMishra at this method --
 $('#productList tr td input[name="linetotal"]').on('change', function(){
  var net_value =0;
  $('#productList tr td input[name="linetotal"]').each(function() {
   net_value+= +($(this).val());  donot u think this.val() u need to parse with Rs symbol.

Comment: did u print these values .. and also u need to set .netamount value after for each loop .

Comment: @Neha: "document.forms[0].elements" There are no such type of methods available.

Comment: Actually i was used this script for only testing purpose. actual script is $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#productList tr td input[name="linetotal"]').on('change', function(){
  var net_value =0;
  $('#productList tr td input[name="linetotal"]').each(function() {
   net_value+= +($(this).val().replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '' ));
   $('input[name="net_ammount"]').val(net_value);
  })
  
 })
})

Comment: @IshanJain there is elements[] and its not methods its array of all elements in the form. please check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: @SatendraMishra do u able to print on console or alert those values ? andother thing $("input[name="net_amount").. line should be out of each function.

Comment: @Neha this is jquery script. I was used the logic when linetotal input value changed the loop is started and compute every value. but it seems when data comes from the server .change() method does not work.

Comment: @Neha: try this one - http://jsfiddle.net/TrGgq/2/

Comment: @IshanJain I am not sure how this help? please let me know what u wana point out.

Comment: @SatendraMishra why not call this script when server update the input box (when u know server value come..)rather onchange as i notice sometime on change server not update value quickly enough.

Comment: @Neha: nono there is no special reason to post this, it's only what i am implement... :)

Comment: @Neha may be, but i dont know about any jquery method which is triggerd when input is updated. did you know ?

Comment: @Ishan Jain Your effort is praiseworthy. but I can not use it. I want when product is changed value autometically added in net ammount

Comment: I think this will work - $('input[name=myInput]').change(function() { ... }); but try it out .. meanwhile i will try on fiddle.

Comment: may be this will helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery  OR  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072159/detecting-change-in-a-text-input-box-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: $Neha this script i have already tried but it is not work.  OnChange event fires when text box loses focus and the value within the text box has changed. but in case value has changed but focus does not loss. because line total does not get any focus before he change. data comes from the server.

Comment: hmm i also notice its while trying.. but u know line where server setting input values so after that why not call the method to calc netamount.

Comment: @Neha I was tried on when product changed but .chenge() event triggered before value comes from server. I am very upset, about this strange challenge. do you know someone who could solve it?

Comment: ok hows ur server data coming by ajax ?? if ajax then at success call method suppose - calculatet();  which is like function calculate () { var net_value =0; $('#productList tr td input[name="linetotal"]').each(function() { net_value+= +($(this).val().replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '' )); $('input[name="net_ammount"]').val(net_value); }) }) }

Comment: @Neha if you dont mind can we chat in google chat or another places where you can ?

Comment: My complete ajax code can not pasted in comment box this is large

Comment: join this - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49208/sum-of-total

Comment: I'm confused where can i type my reply in chat room ?

Comment: give ur gmail id i will ping u.

Comment: engineersatendra@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

ID can never be same ,Id is unique,classes can be same (multiple) in HTML
I by mistake put it in comment instead of answer box :)

Comment: Ok I will correct my mistake, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Then Edit the Question,Make unique ID so I can solve problem

Comment: Okay question has been edited.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you make the id of your "Net Amount" input element, "summary_net_amount", the answer is something like this:

```
function calculateLineTotals(){
    var $linetotals = $("input[name=\"linetotal\"]");
    var sum = 0;
    $linetotals.each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#summary_net_amount").val(sum);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this type logic in my script but this is not work. you can see my actual page in http://www.lpgbookkeeping.in/ userid: blueflame2014 pwd: Blueflame@2014

Comment: How do I get to the table view?

Comment: please visit my site lpgbookkeeping.in www.lpgbookkeeping.in after login go to new purchase order entry sub menu under the supplier menu

Comment: What kind of error/problem are you getting when you do this?

Comment: Assuming you have understood my problem. Actually I want whn user change product code in datagrid every time related line total value compute in net ammount value.

Comment: Which page is this on Your web site.?

Comment: @PratikJoshi after login go to new purchase order entry sub menu under the supplier menu