# How to prevent '0' to be the first char entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, character, zero

How to easily prevent `0` from being the first char entered in a textbox with JavaScript? I want something like the .Net `OnKeyDown()`. When the user presses <kbd>0</kbd> key for the first char to be prevented

```
e.Handled = true;
```

---

Why doesnt this work?

```
function PreventFirstCharZero()
{
var TB = document.getElementById("idbox").value;
var TextLength = TB.value.length;

if (48 == event.keyCode && 0 == TextLength)
{
    event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

---

This doesn't work

```
function PreventFirstCharZero()
{
    if ('0' == document.getElementById("idbox")[0].value)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: use onKeyPress="myFunction() and handle that is javascript

Comment: Ok in myFuncion() whats the javascript alternative of e.Handled = true;

Comment: event.preventDefault()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this!

```
$("#input").on("keypress keyup",function(){
    if($(this).val() == '0'){
      $(this).val('');  
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vM8U9/)

Comment: When you enter other numbers first then enter zero at the beginning it stays there

Answer (score 6):

Try this http://jsbin.com/sanoz/4/edit

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    if(this.value.charAt(0) === '0')
        this.value = this.value.slice(1);
});
```

You can prevent paste using:

```
<input onpaste="return false;" id="input"/>
```

or have a look at this: [detecting change in a text input box using jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072159/detecting-change-in-a-text-input-box-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Vanilla JS not jQuery

Comment: Works but if you paste using the mouse it lets the zero stay. I would suggest repeating the exact same thing but listening for the `onchange` event.

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet, pure javascript one-liner:

```
<input onkeyup="if (event.srcElement.value.charAt(0) == '0') { event.srcElement.value = event.srcElement.value.slice(1); }" />
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQcCS/2)

Comment: it disable typing zero at any position

Comment: i need to disable 0 only at first posisition. pure fail

Answer (score 0):

To be honnest, prevent a key to be entered isn't a good solution since you can always copy/past and the event will not trigger.

If i may suggest you an other solution, use `change` (or `blur` since change doesnt work in all browser apparently) event and remove the first char if it's a 0:

```
document.getElementById('noZero').addEventListener('blur', checkZero)

function checkZero(){
    var val = this.value;
    if(val.charAt(0) === '0')
        this.value = val.slice(1), checkZero.call(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F5ZSA/6/

---

If you absolutly want a key event, you can change `'change'` to `'keyup'` and it will work, but will still be able to rightclick and paste without triggering the `keyup` event;

Comment: This looks the best solution so far but you might change 'change' to keyup.

Comment: @AamirAfridi as i said right after the fiddle link : *"If you absolutly want a key event, you can change 'change' to 'keyup' and it will work, but will still be able to rightclick and paste without triggering the keyup event;"*

Comment: Yes but 'change' doesn't work. At least its not working for me in Chrome.

Comment: @AamirAfridi wierd, it is working fine for me (chrome also) with the exception of a little bug i just corrected.

Comment: @AamirAfridi I don't know the compatibility of `change`, changed for `blur`. But thank for pointing out.

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="Prevent(this.value)" id="testInput" />
```

### javascript

```
function Prevent(value) {
    var x = document.getElementById("testInput");
    if (value == 'O') {
        x.value = '';
    }
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/72s4G/)

Comment: @AamirAfridi it is configured for first char not to be capital O and it does not take it. am i missing anything here??